# I want to validate a user input with this function but the loop just keeps repeating even after the correct parameters have been met

Tags: python-3.x

This function is used to validate the user input

```
    height = int(input('Enter an odd number 5 or greater: '))
    while True:
        if height % 2 == 0 and height < 5:
            int(input("Error! Try again "))    #This function is used to validate the user input
    
 
        elif (height % 2) != 0 and height >= 5:
            print(height)
```

Comment: add ```break``` after the ```print``` statement

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `elif (height % 2) != 0 and height >= 5`, you can use a cleaner `if-else` clause.

```
    height = int(input('Enter an odd number 5 or greater: '))
    while True:
        if (height % 2) != 0 and height >= 5:
            print(height)
            break   #to exit the loop

        else :
            height = int(input("Error! Try again "))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it seems like if the user enters the wrong input lets say 2 times. but then answers in correctly the function still prints the error message. got any idea why?

Comment: Updated the answer. You weren't storing the input in the ```height``` variable